# Is there a way to compute scalar products while keeping cache locality?

Tags: c, caching, numerical

Suppose I have two arrays of `float`s of same length `n`:

```
float *a, *b;
int n;
```

I'd like to compute their scalar product. The naive way would be this:

```
int i;
float result=0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  result += a[i]*b[i];
```

But from a data locality point of view this is terrible, especially if `n` is large or if `a` and `b` are far apart in memory. On each iteration we alternate fetching values from `a` and `b`. Is there a way I can make this more efficient?

Comment: You're only making a single sequential pass through each array. Two strides is fine. So I doubt you can do much better - unless of course you have an outer loop.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are unlucky enough that a and b both map to the same cache line then the processor will have its fetch pipeline full almost all the time. Data non-locality and stride can be big issues in larger, squarer arrays but here I think you have very little to worry about.

If you interleaved a and b values then both floats would fit in a single fetch on a 64-bit machine, which might help matters (although memory alignment issues make this architecture-dependent.)